# Based on Molecular Orbital Theory , how is it decided that the double bond in O2 molecule has one sigma bond and one pi bond?

Tags: molecular-orbital-theory

My Chemistry textbook says this in regard to a C2 molecule:

> It is important to note that double bond
>   in C2 consists of both pi bonds because of the
>   presence of four electrons in two pi molecular
>   orbitals.

Is it possible to account for the double bond in an Oxygen atom consisting of a sigma bond and a pi bond in the same way, based on MOT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[$\ce{O2}$ MO diagram](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:O2MolecularDiagramCR.jpg)

From the MO diagram, we can see that it has 2 electrons in a $\sigma$ orbital, 4 in $\pi$ orbitals, and 2 in $\pi$* orbitals. Taking this together gives a bond order 2, with 1 coming from the sigma electrons and another 1 being the net value for the $\pi$ and $\pi$* electrons.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the brilliant answer! So we have to use this method for checking type of bonds are present between 2 atoms in a molecule? Didn't find it anywhere else...

Comment: It becomes a bit more complicated for anything beyond diatomic molecules and there are cases where it fails (e.g. CO) but this is how the concept of bond order is generally introduced at a general chemistry level.